# Getting ReactJS to work with SocketIO and RxJS

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm having trouble getting the below code to work.

I can get the data using just SocketIO but not with RxJS 6.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
    state = {
      clusterdata: {}
    }
  componentDidMount(){
    const socket = io('http://localhost:5000',{
      path: '/stream',
      transports: ['websocket']
    });
    socket.emit('json', 'my-ecs-cluster');
      const clusterStream = Observable.create(observer => {
        socket.on('connect', socket => {
            console.log(socket);
          socket.on('json', data => {
            observer.next(data)
          })
      })
        this.clusterStreamObserver = clusterStream.subscribe(this.setClusterData.bind(this));
    })
```

... the setState part

```
setClusterData(clusterdata){
     if (!clusterdata || clusterdata.length === 0) {
       return;
       this.setState({clusterdata: clusterdata});
     }
  }
```

... the render part

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.clusterdata)}

        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can find all details on how to use Observables over socketIO [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reactive-thinking-how-to-design-a-distributed-system-with-rxjs-websockets-and-node-57d772f89260) in this article or  [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1?t=1&cn=ZmxleGlibGVfcmVjcw%3D%3D&refsrc=email&iid=9b197a27b4a14948b1d2fd4ad999e0a1&uid=39235406&nid=244%20276893704) in this other article

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create an Observable by the following way:

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000',{
      path: '/stream',
      transports: ['websocket']
    });

const connection$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'connect');

connection$.subscribe();

Comment: This works, thanks: 

socket.on('connect', sock => {
      socket.emit('json', 'my-ecs-cluster');
      const clusterStream = fromEvent(socket, 'json')
      this.clusterStreamObserver = clusterStream.subscribe(this.setClusterData.bind(this));
    })
   }